# StructureMap profiles and web requests question

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, structuremap

I want to have several different versions of my software based on a parameter passed in on the request.  I'm currently trying to accomplish this with profiles.

What I need to know is, if I have something like (pseudo)

```
ObjectFactory.Profile = Request.Params["version"];
var instance = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(...);
```

is it possible for a competing request to change the profile before structure map has finished  constructing my instance and it's dependencies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting a lock around the construction code?